# how to display a UIView in a social media post

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, twitter, uiview

I don't even know if this is possible but I was wondering if there is anyway you can insert a UIView and all its contents into a tweet or facebook post so when the user sends out a tweet from the app, an image of the UIView is displayed in the tweet. Any help is appreciated. Here is my attempt where it says //THIS LINE DOES NOT DO ANYTHING:

```
func sendSocialPost(serviceType:String) {

    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(serviceType) {

        // Users device is good for Twitter
        let socialDialog:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: serviceType)

        socialDialog.setInitialText("Whats the mood like?")

        // THIS LINE DOES NOT DO ANYTHING
        socialDialog.inputAccessoryView?.insertSubview(self.scrollViewView, aboveSubview: self.contentView)

        socialDialog.completionHandler = { (result:SLComposeViewControllerResult) in

            // Check if the user sent the tweet of cancelled it
            if result == SLComposeViewControllerResult.Done {
                // User has sent social post
                NSLog("post sent")
            }
            else if result == SLComposeViewControllerResult.Cancelled {
                NSLog("post cancelled")
            }
        }

        // Present the social dialog box
        self.presentViewController(socialDialog, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    else {

        // Social Account credentials haven't been added to the settings
        if serviceType == SLServiceTypeTwitter {
            NSLog("A Twitter account needs to be set up in the Settings app.")
        }
        else if serviceType == SLServiceTypeFacebook {
            NSLog("A Facebook account needs to be set up in the Settings app.")
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture a view to a UIImage and tweet that..
If that's what you mean..

```
    func captureViewArea() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.viewToCapture.bounds.size, self.viewToCapture.opaque, 0.0)
        self.viewToCapture.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return viewImage
    }
```